# How to disable DTD validation in LSParser?

Tags: java, dom

I use the following code to parse an XML file and to construct the `Document` node.

```
    String oldValue = System.getProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY);
    System.setProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY,
            "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMImplementationSourceImpl");
    DOMImplementationRegistry domImplementationRegistry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
    DOMImplementationLS domImplementation = (DOMImplementationLS) domImplementationRegistry
            .getDOMImplementation("LS");
    LSInput lsInput = domImplementation.createLSInput();
    InputStream xmlInputStream = xmlFile.getInputStreamForReading();
    lsInput.setByteStream(xmlInputStream);
    LSParser lsParser = domImplementation.createLSParser(DOMImplementationLS.MODE_SYNCHRONOUS, null);
    DOMConfiguration domConfig = lsParser.getDomConfig();
    if(domConfig.canSetParameter("validate-if-schema", Boolean.FALSE) && domConfig.canSetParameter("validate", Boolean.FALSE)){
        domConfig.setParameter("validate-if-schema", Boolean.FALSE);
        domConfig.setParameter("validate", Boolean.FALSE);
    }
    xmlDocument = lsParser.parse(lsInput);
    if (oldValue != null) {
        System.setProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY, oldValue);
    }
```

The problem I have is that when `parse` is invoked on the `lsParser` an `org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException` is thrown. Regarding DTD validation I only found information to deactivate validation w.r.t. `DocumentBuilderFactory` in the following way:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory .setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

But unfortunately not in context with the `LSParser`. How is this realisable?

Comment: No ideas on this issue?

Comment: Am I the first who encountered this issue?

Comment: Did I something wron? Maybe I added the wrong flags? I really much appreciate any hints to get this question answered.